# Why cant get device id in non-Main Class?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I retrieve the device ID in my main activity by doing:

```
String UDID = System.getString(this.getContentResolver(), System.ANDROID_ID);
```

Later in my code I start a new Activity in which I need the UDID as well, but when I run the same line of code it crashes:

```
01-01 12:20:54.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 12:20:54.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 12:20:54.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)
```

I understand that it has to do something with the context, but cant figure out how to fix this. Of course I could do putExtra, but I guess there must be a better way.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me though this is deprecated

```
 String id_deprecated = System.getString(this.getContentResolver(),      
                                         android.provider.Settings.System.ANDROID_ID);
```

You should use the ANDROID_ID defined in Settings.Secure

```
 String id_new =System.getString(this.getContentResolver(), 
                                    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Still crashes, even with id_new.

01-01 13:54:30.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)

Comment: Are you sure 'this' is an instance of an activity?